# Merge "area51-discussion" with "area51"

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, meta, retag-request

Considering that Area 51 has its own discussion place, which is also its meta site, having [area51-discussion](/questions/tagged/area51-discussion) and [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) is useless. A discussion about Area 51, is still a discussion, and those questions can be tagged with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and [area51](/questions/tagged/area51).

In fact, [17 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-discussion+area51) (out of 24 tagged [area51-discussion](/questions/tagged/area51-discussion)) use [area51-discussion](/questions/tagged/area51-discussion) and [area51](/questions/tagged/area51); [8 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-discussion+discussion) use [area51-discussion](/questions/tagged/area51-discussion) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion); [7 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-discussion+discussion+area51) use [area51-discussion](/questions/tagged/area51-discussion), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and [area51](/questions/tagged/area51).

[area51-discussion](/questions/tagged/area51-discussion) and [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) should be merged.

Comment: Nitpick, Area 51's meta is either "Area 51 Discussion Zone" or "Area 51 Discussions" - not the singular discussion. :) That said, it looks like the plural version is also merged into the area51 tag along with the singular.